# How to combine two nested parent array of objects javascript that have same parent?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

hi guys I have some problem when combining two nested parent array of object , I want to combine only children item when having same group parent.
this my case:
i have two array

```
var arr1 = [{group: "a", items: ["a","b","c","d"]}, {group: "b", items:["k","l","m"]}];

var arr1 = [{group: "b", items: ["o","p","q","r"]}, {group: "c", items:["1","2","3","4"]}]
```

I want to combine these two array. if the second array has same parent group it will be just pushed of items, there is the expectation of result:

```
[
  {
     group: "a",
     items: ["a","b","c","d"]
  },
  {
     group: "b",
     items: ["k","l","m","o","p","q", "r"]
  },
  {
     group: "c",
     items: ["1","2","3","4"]

  },
]
```

in this case, arr1 and arra2 have the same **b** group. it will union only the item. I have searched everywhere but I still have no idea. please help me. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine two arrays first and using `Array.prototype.reduce`, group them by `group` key.

```js
var arr1 = [{group: "a", items: ["a","b","c","d"]}, {group: "b", items:["k","l","m"]}];
var arr2 = [{group: "b", items: ["o","p","q","r"]}, {group: "c", items:["1","2","3","4"]}]

const groupBy = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.group] ? acc[cur.group].items = [ ...acc[cur.group].items, ...cur.items ] : acc[cur.group] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(groupBy);
console.log(output);
```